# mongoose text search on specified fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my schema below, how do I **separate search** for `name` and `email`?

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: Array,
  description: String,
  others: String
});

schema.index({name: 'text', 'email': 'text'});
```

The cilent would pass search_option, either name or email, currently I do search for both. If name has 'abc', the result will return 'abc@gmail.com' which is not what I want.

```
MyModel.find({$text: {$search: searchString}})
       .exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Comment: MongoDB supports only "one" text index per collection. Once you define it then those are the fields you are searching on. You want a `$regex` search for what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah figured that out partially, how to turn off case insenstive? tried this it work in case sensitive mode. `const result = await myModel.aggregate([
  {$match: { email: { $regex: searchQuery} }},
])`

Comment: I do `const result = await myModel.aggregate([
  {$match: { email: { $regex: searchQuery, $option: 'i' } }},
])` I got `"unknown operator: $option"`. But the doc has it https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex

Comment: @Melissa92 Try `$options`, not `$option`

Comment: @MForMarlon oh thanks!